# Honda Grace, temperature problem

Tags: honda, hybrid

My Car is a Honda Grace,well checked and we'll maintained.Morning when I start the vehicle,engine temperature bulb(along with other indicator bulbs)comes in blue and disappear.After a hour of ride,when I start the engine again in 15 minutes for a ride all the bulbs comes out as usual,but,the engine temperature bulb this time will show in red and disappear as usuall. Is this normal?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Its normal. Having it blue after starting for sometime and later it goes off is normal